# InflateException i have an Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, view, inflate, inflate-exception

I have more activities and i dont have any problem but when i'm starting this activity(Segunda) it break
In this Activity I try to use a customView for zoom and draw, and i cant find where is the problem

this is the activity

```
public class Segunda extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);
        //setContentView(new Panel(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);      
    }
}
```

this is the xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.andres.sun4all.Panel 
    android:id="@+id/Panelillo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_weight = "2">

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andres.sun4all/com.andres.sun4all.Segunda}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.andres.sun4all.Panel
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.andres.sun4all.Panel
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.andres.sun4all.Segunda.onCreate(Segunda.java:13)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    ... 11 more
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
10-21 12:43:58.191: E/AndroidRuntime(27794):    ... 22 more
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't closed your outer LinearLayout

Comment: haha,nah, i just didnt copy the last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

it means that your custom view `Panel` is missing the constructor with the context and attributeset:

```
  public void Panel(Context context, AttributeSet att) {
       super(context,att)    
  }
```

which is used when the custom view is inflated from the xml

Comment: //I have this
 public Panel(Context context) {
  super(context);
  
  if(Main.check){
   this.setOnTouchListener(clickPinta);
  }
  else{
   this.setOnTouchListener(clickImagen);
  }
  //imageView.setOnTouchListener(clickImagen);
  //this.setOnTouchListener(clickImagen);
  String s = "http://i.imgur.com/CQzlM.jpg";
  //bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.canguro);
  //probando
  
  
 }

Comment: you have to add `Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attr)`

Comment: thank you! solved! now there is another prob but activity starts thx